# How to deal with nullable reference types with System.Text.Json?

Tags: json, .net-core-3.0, nullable-reference-types, system.text.json

I have upgraded my project to netcore 3.0 and I am in the middle of refactoring a project to use the new nullable references types feature, but got stuck pretty quickly because of the following issue.

Lets say I consume a REST api which returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "Name": "Volvo 240",
  "Year": 1989
}
```

This api always returns the name/year, so they are non-nullable.

I would use this simple class for deserialization:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}
}
```

And I would deserialize this to a `Car` instance using the new `System.Text.Json`

```cs
var car = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(json);
```

This all works, but when enabling nullable reference types I get a warning in the `Car` class that `Name` is declared as non-nullable but can be null. I understand why I get this since it is possible to instantiate this object without initializing the `Name` property.

So ideally `Car` should look like this:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Year { get; }

    public Car(string name, int year)
    {
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because `System.Text.Json` serializer doesn't support constructors with parameters.

So my question is: How would I declare `Car` so that `Name` is non-nullable and get it to work with `System.Text.Json` without getting "non-nullable" warning?`

I don't want to make it nullable because I would have to do null-checks on basically everything when enabling nullable reference types, and since the REST API in my example says that they are always provided they shouldn't be nullable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`System.Text.Json` for .NET 5 now supports parameterized constructors, so this should not be a problem anymore.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0

**Old answer below**

After reading the [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references) I found out how I could solve this issue.

So until `System.Text.Json` cannot instantiate classes with parameters in their constructor, the `Car` class will have to look like this:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would rather use `= "";`, as otherwise you're basically saying (in my opinion) "This property is never going to be null (**just kidding**)".

Comment: Or use JSON.NET. System.Text.Json isn't a complete replacement *yet*. . As for `= default` ... not yet. When I read that in October 2019 I think `You are setting this to null!`. Maybe next year.

Comment: This is similar to what Microsoft recommends with entity objects. The EF team actually recommends using `null!` as a way of saying, 'I know this is never `null`.' Even though I like the potential of this nullability stuff, this sure feels a bit off...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Note that in the context of asp.net, adding `= null!` is actually the correct way to decorate a required property on an request object. It is the successor to the `[Required]` attribute. Adding `= null!` will simply tell the compiler that you know what you are doing, it will **not** allow the string to be deserialized to null. Since the string is non-nullable, asp.net will reject any requests that don't specify a value for the non-nullable/required reference type. Note that doing a `#nullable disable` will **actually** disable the null restriction -- so don't do that!

Comment: @MattJacobi `System.Text.Json` will happily deserialize `null` into a non-nullable string property; at least by default, regardless of the `#nullable` status of the deserialized class (I just tried) - is there some options that triggers this stricter "I really mean nullability" mode?

Comment: (both explicit null and implicit nulls by property ommission are not nullability errors by default for System.Text.Json)

Comment: Just to echo what @EamonNerbonne said, System.Text.Json and even Json.Net, don't support nullable reference types. They will happily set a non-nullable string to null which is a pretty big gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
If you're on `net5`, use the parameterized constructor support now offer as @langen points out. Else below can still be useful.

**Original**
Slightly alternative approach. `System.Text.Json` appears to have no problems using a private parameterless constructor. So you can at least do the following:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    // For System.Text.Json deserialization only
    #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized.
    private Car() { }
    #pragma warning restore CS8618

    public Car(string name, int year)
    {
        Name = name
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Year = year;
    }
}
```

Benefits being:

- Init of the object from your own code must be through the public ctor.
- You don't need to do  `= null!;` on each property.

Remaining downside with S.T.Json and nullable reference types:

- S.T.Json still requires setters on the properties to actually set the values during deserialization. I tried with private ones and it's a no go, so we still can't get an immutable object...

Comment: FYI, both System.Text.Json and Json.Net support parameterized constructors but they don't support nullable reference types. Using your example code, both deserializers will happy set the `Name` property to `null` which is pretty big gotcha.

Comment: It's always a good idea to null check and throw in the ctor as you can't really trust others, good point.

Comment: Throwing an exception in the ctor causes ASP.net to return a 500 which is not a great. The ideal behavior is ASP.net returns a 4XX and tell the client what went wrong.

Comment: To be fair, the original question wasn't really about model binding, which is always a bit painful. FWIW, ASP.NET Core 6 now considers nullability in model binding/validation and automatically returns a 400 Bad Request. Not sure if throwing in the ctor would cause a 500 still though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, for those who want to handle missing properties with meaningful exceptions:

```cs
using System;

public class Car
{
    private string? name;
    private int? year;

    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(this.Name)} was not set.");
        set => this.name = value;
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get => this.year ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(this.Year)} was not set.");
        set => this.year = value;
    }
}
```